# Privacy of Google Drive links

Tags: google-drive

Sometimes [posts on SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/369141/what-do-the-following-markings-mean-on-a-pcb) contain links to Google Drive documents, which is fine I guess. If I click on the link can they see who opened the link? Or, more specifically, if I open a public Google Drive link does that revel my Google identity to the owner of the drive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your details are not revealed. While you are actively viewing the document, other people viewing the document (including the owner) will see an icon representing you, but the name on the icon is random as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: example]